# Publish a Google Drive Website with custom Domain

Tags: google-drive-api

[i've heard](http://www.slashgear.com/google-drive-launches-website-publishing-29258945/) that you could publish a static website in google drive in a public folder, and i'm wondering how can i configure my domain to that website hosted in drive.

Thank you

Comment: You could try framing.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13636286/632951

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now, you cannot map your own custom domain to Google Drive hosting (i.e. using CNAME or A records), but you can do one of these:

- Set a redirection on your domain to Google Drive, e.g. by uploading an `index.php` file with `<?php header("Location: https://googledrive.com/host/VERYLONGFOLDERID"); ?>`
- Use the free service [G Drives](http://gdriv.es), which provides custom short URLs (aliases) for Google Drive hosting

Answer (score 2):

Link to blogpost about this:
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html

Link to Google Drive SDK documentation:
http://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site

Comment: But there's nothing about adding custom domain.